# Why my expression in StringOps.foreach is not correct

Tags: scala

I try to calculate the product of the unicode values of a String using foreach.

```
scala> var s:Long = 1;"Hello".foreach(s *= _)
s: Long = 9415087488

scala> var s:Long = 1;"Hello".foreach(s = s * _)
<console>:10: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => s.$times(x$1))
       "Hello".foreach(s = s * _)
                               ^
```

I wonder why s = s * _ isn't correct here, what's the difference between s *= _ and s = s * _

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature for the foreach function is:

```
def foreach(f: (A) => Unit): Unit
```

That is, it takes a function from type `A` to `Unit` for some appropriate type `A`.

So this is what I believe is happening:

In the first instance, the compiler interprets the expression `s *= _` as the right-hand side of the function f (an expression returning `Unit` - ie nothing - meaning it is executed only for its side-effect - in this case updating the value of s). Because there is an underscore in this expression, the compiler assumes a suitable left-hand side for f.

In the second instance, the compiler can interpret the expression `s = s * _` as both the left and right hand sides of f, so the `s` of `s =` should define the type `A` of the expression, but then it doesn't know what the underscore represents and complains.

I should note also that a more idiomatic, functional style of performing this sort of calculation would be to use a fold:

```
scala> val s = "Hello".foldLeft(1L)(_ * _)
s: Long = 9415087488
```